# Difference between session and caching

Tags: asp.net, session, caching

Can anyone list  the major differences between session and caching?
Because it seems to me as the same, like sessions are also stored on server and caching. Also, session is used to store the data to reuse, caching too, what exactly could be the major difference that Microsoft created these two components?
A real world scenario would be more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions are per user session.

Cache is not - it is for *everyone*.

Comment: but i can set the session timeout as i set the expiration for cache, which will expire the session after specific time

Comment: @Abbas: Yes, but what Oded is saying is that ONLY that session will see the data while it lives.

Answer (score 0):

A session is data cached for one specific user session.  When the user logs out or the session expires, that data is gone, and other uses won't tap into that data.
Cache is typically used across user sessions (IE something is cached for all user sessions, not just the current user session).

Answer (score 0):

Session is essentially a special-case of a cache that tracks a 'session' of web requests/responses.

'Cache' is a heavily-used term that generally means 'store something in a faster media' than it normally would be stored in.

Starting on the server there are a variety of ways ASP.NET and IIS can cache for you. On the way to the client you have proxies and CDN's. Then at the browser you have caching rules for the content.

As Raymond Chen says, "A poor cache policy is indistinguishable from a memory leak."